# Performance of write() in Python 2.7?

Tags: performance, file-io, python-2.7, windows-7

I'm finding performance of write() to be extra-ordinarly slow on Windows 7, using Python 2.7.3. This is compared to the same code running on my laptop with Archlinux, which performs in order of 10 - 30x faster at least. Am I doing something wrong, are there parameters I can adjust to try and help things? Should I be using writelins() instead of write()?

The specific scenario is as follows:

For each line of a file, write a line to two other files. I'm basically re-formatting the file.

The file in question is approximately 350MB in size, containing somewhere around 200.000 lines. On my laptop running Archlinux the process gets done in somewhere around 1-2 minutes. On Windows, 22 minutes in it has only written 165MB. This wouldn't be a problem if it was a one-time thing, but as I will be handing this to others to run I'd like to figure out if I can't improve this somehow. There are five of these files, that means a several-hours process.

Relevant code:

```
    with open('%s/%s.dat' % (cacheDir, f_from), 'r') as old_file:
         with open('%s/%s.dat' % (vectorsDir, f_to), 'w+') as dat_file:
             with open('%s/%s.idx' % (vectorsDir, f_to), 'w+') as idx_file:
                dat_text = ''
                idx_text = ''
                for line in old_file:
                    data = line.split()
                    cats = self.ids[data[0]]
                    dat_line = '%s %s\n' % (string.join(cats,','), string.join(data[1:]))
                    idx_line = '%s\n' % data[0]
                    dat_text += dat_line
                    idx_text += idx_line
                    dat_file.write(dat_line)        
                    idx_file.write(idx_line)
                return dat_text, idx_text
```

Comment: (1) How confident are you that the OS is the relevant factor?  Are the hard drives of the two machines comparable?  (2) Have you tried specifying a large write buffer when opening `dat_file` and `idx_file`?

Comment: (1) I'm not, to be fair. The hard drives are both 7200RPM SATA2 hard-drives that pass S.M.A.R.T, and the laptop drive is actually a lot older. (2) I've tried buffers of 20MB, 50MB and 100MB. It seems to make almost no difference to speed.

I won't have a chance to test this on another Windows machine until tomorrow, but when I do I'll report back whether I see the same behavior or not.

Comment: Some other (purely speculative) thoughts:  (a) What does the memory usage on the Windows machines look like?  You're building up some large strings; perhaps you're starting to swap.  Is it faster if you don't accumulate data in `dat_text` and `idx_text`?

Comment: (b) You're alternatingly hitting three different files.  It's possible that on the Windows machine the layout of the files on disk is unfortunate and rotational latency for that access pattern is hurting you.  If you have enough memory, try reading in `old_file` all at once, then do one iteration where you write to `dat_file` and another iteration where you write to `idx_file`.  Does that change the overall time?

Comment: (BTW, although I'm not familiar with how Windows performs IO buffering, I'd guess that 20MB is far too large, and all you're doing is causing more work for the kernel.  I was thinking of something more along the lines of 4k or 16k.)

Comment: The culprit seems to have been the string addition to idx_text and dat_text. Curious that this doesn't give the same kind of problem on my Linux installation! I've upvoted the comment, but is there any way to set a comment as an answer?

Comment: Glad it got sorted out.  I'll repost as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Reposting a comment as answer.)

What does memory usage on the Windows machine look like? You're building up some large strings in memory; perhaps that's resulting in swapping.  Is it faster if you don't accumulate data in `dat_text` and `idx_text`?